# clojure overtone (at command)

Tags: clojure, overtone

What does `at` do actually in clojure? I saw this example in internet making a loop for overtone and cant get the meaning of `at`:

```
(defn looper [nome sound]
  (let [beat (nome)]
     (at (nome beat) (sound))
      (apply-at (nome (inc beat)) looper nome sound [])))`
```

Comment: and if someone knows of a good tutorial for overtone for an absolute beginner, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The `at` command is a part of overtone, not Clojure.

The overtone cheatsheet shows that it is a timing function:

https://github.com/overtone/overtone/raw/master/docs/cheatsheet/overtone-cheat-sheet.pdf

Also you can look at both github and the wiki:

https://github.com/overtone/overtone
https://github.com/overtone/overtone/wiki
http://overtone.github.io/